# Time-domain functions $f(t)$ whose Fourier Transform is $f(w)$

Tags: fourier-transform, gaussian-integral

The Fourier Transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian with $w$ in place of $t$. Are there other functions whose Fourier Transform results in the same function as the original time-domain function (with $w$ substituted for $t$)? I have stumbled on a function that "appears" (by numerical methods) to satisfy the same conditions;

$$f(t) = \frac{e^{t/2}-e^{-t/2}}{e^t-e^{-t}}.$$

However I am unable to derive the proof so far.

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.systems.caltech.edu/dsp/ppv/papers/journal08post/PPVIETEeigenFT.pdf)

Comment: With the $e^{2i\pi \xi x}$ normalization, if $g$ is any (say $L^2$) function then $g + \hat{g}+\hat{\hat{g}}+ \hat{\hat{\hat{g}}}$ is its own Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you very much, the paper is very informative!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(t) = \frac{e^{t/2}-e^{-t/2}}{e^t-e^{-t}}  = \frac{1}{e^{t/2}+e^{-t/2}}= \frac{1}{2 \cosh t/2}.$$

This is a well known Fourier transform.

On page 81 and forward in Stein and Shakarchi, **Complex Analysis**, Chapter 2, Example 3, the authors show:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi i x \xi}}{\cosh \pi x} \, dx = \frac{1}{\cosh \pi \xi}.$$

This Fourier transform pair, $\left(\frac{1}{\cosh \pi x} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\cosh \pi \xi}\right),$ also appears on the dust jacket of the book!

To summarize the proof, in case you don't have the book (why not?):

Let $f(z)=\frac{\exp\{ -2\pi i z \xi\}}{\cosh \pi z}.$

Compute

$$\oint f(z)\,dz =\oint \frac{\exp\{ -2\pi i z \xi\}}{\cosh \pi z} \, dz. $$

Take a rectangular contour, in the counter-clockwise direction, $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis, from $R$ to $R+2i$, from $R+2i$ to $-R+2i$ and from $R-2i$ to $-R$.  This contour encloses poles at $\alpha=i/2$ and $\beta=3i/2$.  The integrals along the vertical legs of the rectangle go to zero as $R\to\infty$.  Compute residues at $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and apply the residue formula.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You are welcome!